# EditText showing black background

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have created EditText also created xml for this background like below attached code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/login_editext_blue_border"/>
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/login_editext_blue_border"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/login_editext_grey_border"/>
```

then I have added this as background of EditText

I use this as my app theme

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

Now If run my application then the EditText background showing as a black background like below image in android Galaxy S3 mini 4.1.2
[image]

please suggest the solution for this.

Comment: what is your drawable color which you set in item.. Post your drawable code here..

Comment: android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background_normal". Add this code to your xml file inside edittext fields.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:width="1dp" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
</shape>
This is my drawable

Comment: Drawable color is blue and gey

Comment: @AnkushBist I already used the background by this drawable,

Comment: try changing your theme for this activity.

Comment: I checked with this theme for this activity 
<style name="LoginActivityTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: is this code working?

Comment: Not working its also giving the same background. If I remove this border it's working with white background

Comment: <solid android:color="#ffffff"/> working If I add this line in drawable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your drawable like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";     android:shape="rectangle"> 
<stroke android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:width="1dp" /> 
<corners android:radius="4dp" /> 
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
</shape>
```

problem is , you need to add

```
<solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
```

to your drawable in `<shape>` tag.

This might helps you.